# jQuery Errors in Google Dev Tools Console

Tags: jquery

I don't know how to read an error log and would like help doing so. Currently I am trying to figure out the error in my code that lets me have a link jump to a certain id on a page. Here is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('a[href*=#]').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top}, 800, 'linear');
        });
    });
});
```

And here is the error log:

```
jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /self-storage/midland-tx/#facility-page-table
    at Function.fa.error (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at fa.tokenize (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at fa.select (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Function.fa (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at Function.a.find (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
    at n.fn.init.find (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at n.fn.init.a.fn.find (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
    at a.fn.init.n.fn.init (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
    at new a.fn.init (jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2)
    at n (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2)
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you. Please let me know what I may be doing wrong

Here is the HTML

```
    <div class="moving-supplies-page">
    <div id="blurred-image-container">
        <div class="img-src"></div>
        <div class="img-src blurred-image"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="heading-container">
        <div class="heading">
            <h1>Sizes and Prices</h1>
            <p>Sizes and Prices Vary From Location to Location, Please Select Your Location</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="moving-supplies-locations-list">
                <div class="state-name" id="utah">
                    <h2>Utah</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="/self-storage/provo-ut/#facility-page-table"> Provo, Ut</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="state-name" id="texas">
                    <h2>Texas</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a role="button432-978-4561" href="/self-storage/midland-tx/#facility-page-table"> Midland, Tx</a></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="/self-storage/abilene-tx/north-abilene/#facility-page-table"> North 1st Abilene, Tx</a></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="/self-storage/abilene-tx/east-abilene/#facility-page-table"> East Abilene, Tx</a></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="/self-storage/abilene-tx/south-abilene/#facility-page-table"> South 41st Abilene, Tx</a></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="/self-storage/wichita-falls-tx/#facility-page-table"> Wichita Falls, Tx</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="state-name" id="ohio">
                    <h2>Ohio</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> <a href="/self-storage/dayton-oh/#facility-page-table"> Dayton, Oh</a></li> 
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the value of the `href` in question?

Comment: May we see your HTML?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

1. As mentioned by others, the selector needs quotes around the `href` string.
2. You are using the entire `href` for the `scrollTop` selector. Use the ["hash"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hash) portion only.

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var hash = this.hash;
    console.log(hash);
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 800, 'linear');
  });
});
```

```css
#facility-page-table {
  margin: 150vh 0 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="/self-storage/midland-tx/#facility-page-table">Click Here</a>

<div id="facility-page-table">
  Stuff
</div>
```

---

`hash` is [not supported in some browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hash#Browser_compatibility). Here's an alternative:

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var hash = this.href.substring(this.href.indexOf('#'));
    console.log(hash);
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
    }, 800, 'linear');
  });
});
```

```css
#facility-page-table {
  margin: 150vh 0 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="/self-storage/midland-tx/#facility-page-table">Click Here</a>

<div id="facility-page-table">
  Stuff
</div>
```

Comment: What is the value of `this.hash`? e.g. `console.log(this.hash);`

Comment: You'll need to check the value from within your `click` handler. Please see my code, above.

Comment: No element with the ID of "facility-page-table" seems to exist in your HTML.